# IsWebSocketRequest always false in azure

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I have published my websocket on azure and I have enabled the web socket feature in my web app but i keep getting `IsWebSocketRequest` false when i connect to my web socket, note that locally using localhost it is working normally

```csharp
if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)

   context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new TestWebSocketHandler());
```

below is my web app configuration

[image: this is my web app configuration on azure]

Comment: Do you use WS: or WSS: ? Have you tried both of them?

Comment: it worked when i used wss (Y) thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what cause your error.

You could refer to this [sample](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspNet-WebAPI-websockets).

I add `IsWebSocketRequest` in **Get** method, and run in local and on azure it works fine.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string username)
        {
            HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
            if (currentContext.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new ChatWebSocketHandler(username));
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
        }
```